# How to retrieve all messages from someone using lync

Tags: laptop, unix, lync

How can I get all messages from a person I have lync-ed, please?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/communicator-help/find-previous-conversations-HA101834829.aspx) shows you how to accomplish this.

It depends on how your administrator has setup Lync as they may have chosen to disable saving of conversation history or may even have it set to purge after a period of time.

Open Lync, and in your Contacts list, right-click the contact whose previous conversation you want to view.

Click Find Previous Conversations.

Outlook opens and displays that contact’s conversations in the Conversation History folder.